# PHP detect if ImageCreateFromString fail

Tags: php, gd

I would like to be able to detect when i launch this function if it's fail or not **due to the memory size limit**

```
ImageCreateFromString();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php

Comment: `detect when you lunch` ??? .. make your question clear please .....

Comment: @Baba there it is, i'll detect if you can answer now... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PHP-Manual which you've linked there is the solution already written:

**Return Values**

An image resource will be returned on success. FALSE is returned if the image type is unsupported, the data is not in a recognised format, or the image is corrupt and cannot be loaded.

Comment: no it doesn't, work the function output a memory error i would like to do something else if this error is triggered in fact

Answer (score 0):

If you had read the manual you linked in your question, there is an answer already.

> An image resource will be returned on success. FALSE is returned if the image type is unsupported, the data is not in a recognised format, or the image is corrupt and cannot be loaded.

There is an example for that

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
if ($im !== false) {
    // OK
}
else {
    echo 'An error occurred.';
}
```

Comment: i had read the manual, if i've putted the link... the problem is that the function crash on the call, so i don't have any return to deal with

Comment: thanks i just tried that as well it's really the function that make the page to crash, the solution it's that i temporally use getSize() on the file and do something else if the file size is too big, but i'll have to come up with something... I'll give a try to ImageMagick to do the job. I think it require less memory... But i don't have enough time to implement this right now. Anyway thanks for you help ;) By the way i've marked the other solution as valid because my question was not well written and the answer is then valid... ;)

Answer (score -3):

The function returns a string if it succeeded. Therefore you can check if the return is a string or not:

```
if( !is_string(ImageCreateFromString($img)) ) {
    // Do something because it didn't return a string
}
```

Comment: but i do need the result of this function so i tried this: 
if( !is_string($img = ImageCreateFromString($img)) ) {
 return false;
}
but it doesn't work

Comment: the function returns a "resource" object on success, FALSE on error

Comment: if( !is_resource( ImageCreateFromString($img) ) ){}